# Jacoco: merge coverage from @QuarkusTest and @QuarkusIntegrationTest

Tags: quarkus, jacoco

I've followed the steps that I understand should generate a report containing consolidated coverage from all my `@QuarkusTest` and `@QuarkusIntegrationTest` classes, but it seems that @QuarkusTest coverage is ignored.

I add a dependency on quarkus-jacoco:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-jacoco</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I configure the jacoco-maven-plugin:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.10</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <exclClassLoaders>*QuarkusClassLoader</exclClassLoaders>
                <destFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-quarkus.exec</destFile>
                <append>true</append>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>default-prepare-agent-integration</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <destFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-quarkus.exec</destFile>
                <append>true</append>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>report</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-quarkus.exec</dataFile>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-report</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

And I execute a build:

`./mvnw clean verify -Dquarkus.package.write-transformed-bytecode-to-build-output=true`

All tests run and pass, but the report appears to only show coverage from `@QuarkusIntegrationTest`s.  Code that is clearly touched by `@QuarkusTest`s is shown as uncovered.

If I remove the explicit `report` execution section, the report is generated earlier and correctly shows `@QuarkusTest` coverage which proves the stats do get generated, but omits `@QuarkusIntegrationTest` coverage.

It seems like the `<append>true</append>` instructions are being ignored.

Can anyone see what I am missing?

EDIT:   I tried generating distinct exec files for the two types of test and then using the `merge` goal to combine them , but got the same result.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48942083/how-to-merge-2-jacoco-coverage-reports-exec-file-irrespective-of-maven-life-c

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion..  I should have said I'd tried generating distinct exec files for the two types of test and then using the `merge` goal to combine them , but got the same result.  As far as I can tell, outputting the coverage of both test types to the same file with `append=true` should work,   I'm  wonder if there is an additional step I am missing.